# (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format')

Tags: python, api, flask

api_key = None

base_url = None

def configure_request(app):
global api_key,base_url
api_key = app.config['IMAGE_API_KEY']
base_url = app.config['API_BASE_URL']

def get_image(category):

```
get_image_url = base_url.format(api_key,category)

with urllib.request.urlopen(get_image_url) as url:
    get_image_data = url.read()
    get_image_response = json.loads(get_image_data)

    image_results = None

    
    image_results = process_results(get_image_response)
    # print(image_results)

return image_results
```

Answer (score 2):

`app.config['API_BASE_URL']` is `None`. That's all we can tell you.

Comment: And maybe we can't even tell them that. The code shown in the question clearly isn't the *whole* code, because there is no calling code. So maybe the bit of the code that we are *not* being shown has a separate `<object>.format` that is raising the exception. But it's a reasonable guess, and is the answer that the question deserves.